# how to call the printf function based on its address in assembly

Tags: c, assembly

i want to call one function based on its address. but after i try to do that, some trouble come to my eyes. i cant deal with those trouble. i dont know what is going wrong.
please somebody help me to finish the calling action. 
[image link](http://www.97gow.com/files/getFile.ashx?browser=true&name=assambly.jpg)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char* mat = "%s\n";
    char* str = "abc";
    //printf(mat,str);

    _asm
    {
        mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]
        push        eax
        mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4]
        push        ecx
        mov         eax,00401090h //function 'printf' address
        call        [eax]
        //call        printf //dont call like this, we shall call based on its address.
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Why is the code a link to a separate file? **And why is it a picture?**

Comment: Please copy and paste your code inline so people can test it in their own environment. Use the `{}` button with the code selected to format your code.

Comment: How did you determine that `printf` is at `00401090`?  Are you expecting it to always be there?

Comment: @CodyGray: Probably because it's worth a thousand words?

Comment: @Chris: You go above and beyond, sir.

Comment: i want to achieve one function: based on the function address, not based on the function name, call the function in assembly.

Comment: The point is that you can't assume or rely on a function always having the same address, so you can't hard-code the address into your code.

Comment: @DrewDormann trust me, if it were any longer I wouldn't have even tried. user859974 please realize you're only preventing people from helping you by posting your code this way.

Comment: @user859974: There is no chance of us solving the problem of "trouble coming to your eyes".  Please explain the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: There's a reason functions have names.

Comment: -2 and 2 favs, how does that even work

Comment: @pezcode, if you favorite a post you'll be notified when it is updated. I don't really use them as posts I really like, I use them for posts where I want to go back later to see how things turned out. So, ironically, I tend to use favs on low-quality posts where I want to see if the OP straightened out whatever they did wrong the first time around :)

Answer (score 4):

You can not rely on `printf` being at a hard-coded address.

Replace:

```
mov    eax,00401090h
call   [eax]
```

With:

```
call    printf
```

Comment: based on address, not based on function name.

Comment: The function name IS the address.

Comment: And here is the obvious call-an-adress approach: `mov eax, printf; call [eax];`.

Answer (score 2):

The load address of the DLL containing printf can (and does!) vary. This means that the address of printf changes - it might even change across two runs of the same application!

You can do as Drew suggests and replace it with a literal `printf` - the linker will replace this with the proper address of a trampoline routine (which, in turn, may be moved from one compilation to another, or even at runtime if you have a relocatable executable) that will be pointed to the real `printf` at runtime.

Or you can use OS-specific routines to find `printf`'s address yourself at runtime, then invoke using that address (the details are left as an exercise for the reader - I would recommend prototyping this in C first, then translating it a bit at a time to asm). On windows, look for [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); on Unixen, look for [`dlsym`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html).

Comment: Too much OS-specific while question does not specify any OS.

Comment: @m0skit0, he's using Visual C++ inline assembler syntax, so Windows is a good guess, but I made it a bit less OS-specific anyway